# How can I create a variable with different values for each domain using Domain Access?

Tags: 7, domain-access, configuration

I have a numeric value that is unique to each domain (using Domain Access) on my site. I'd like to use the same variable name so I can use the same theme and display this value on all domains. Is this possible?

I'm currently defining the variable in a custom module, but I'm only storing 1 value. Can I alter the code in the custom module so that each domain can have it's own unique value for this variable?

UPDATE:

Adding the following when defining the variable in my custom module worked :D

```
'multidomain' => true,
```

I can edit the variable through admin/config/system/variable/edit/ and I get unique values across my domains stored in the variable_store table. The problem I now have is that I want to create an admin form for getting/setting a bunch of domain variables and the usual variable_get/variable_set don't work...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is how I solved it...I hope this is the "right" way:

Define the variable, 'multidomain' being the import difference

```
function MODULENAME_variable_info($options) {

  $variable['social_media_link_twitter'] = array(
    'title' => t('Twitter', array(), $options),
    'description' => t('Twitter URL', array(), $options),
    'type' => 'string',
    'multidomain' => true,
    'access' => 'social media links'
  );
```

Create a menu to get to the admin form

```
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/social-media-links'] = array(
      'title' => t('Social Media Links'),
      'page callback' => 'MODULENAME_social_media_links_admin',
      'access arguments' => array('social media links'),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Menu Page Callback

```
function MODULENAME_social_media_links_admin() {
  return drupal_get_form('MODULENAME_socialmedialinks_form');
}
```

Form Declaration

```
function MODULENAME_socialmedialinks_form($form_state) {

  /* Just regular old variable_get() */
  $form['social_media_link_twitter'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Twitter'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => t('Enter your twitter URL. Example: http://twitter.com/SomethingOn'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('social_media_link_twitter', '')
  );

  /* return the system settings form, not just $form */
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Form Submit

```
function MODULENAME_socialmedialinks_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  /* For some reason I have to manually get the domain and set the realm?! */
  $domain = domain_get_domain();
  variable_realm_switch('domain', $domain['subdomain']);

  domain_conf_variable_set($domain['domain_id'], 'social_media_link_twitter', $form_state['values']['social_media_link_twitter']);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must enable "domain configuration" submodule (domain_conf)
This will provide you the save per domain option:

```
function your_module_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['variable'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => time(),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);

}
```

getting the variable manually:

```
function domain_conf_variable_get($domain_id, $variable = '', $all = FALSE, $reset = FALSE)
```

seeting the variable manually:

```
function domain_conf_variable_set($domain_id, $variable, $value = NULL)
```

There is a module which aims to be a replacement variable handling module for Domain Access,If you need setting different variable values for each domain and for each language at the same time you need domain variable module https://drupal.org/project/domain_variable

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is with

[hook_domain_batch](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/domain/domain.api.php/function/hook_domain_batch/7.3)

which gives you a nice settings UI under Domain > Settings

For example, I wrote an implementation of that hook for per-domain apachesolr site hash settings:

```
/**
* Implements hook_domain_batch().
*
* Add batch settings to Domain Conf.
*/
function MODULENAME_domain_batch() {

  $batch = array();

  if(function_exists('apachesolr_site_hash')){
    $batch['apachesolr_site_hash'] = array(
      '#form' => array(
        '#title' => t('Apache Solr site hash'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#description' => t('Unique site hash for Apache Solr.'),
      ),
      '#domain_action' => 'domain_conf',
      '#permission' => 'administer site configuration',
      '#system_default' => apachesolr_site_hash(),
      '#meta_description' => t('Set Apache Solr site hash for each domain.'),
      '#variable' => 'apachesolr_site_hash',
      '#data_type' => 'string',
      '#weight' => -1,
      '#group' => t('Apache Solr'),
      '#update_all' => TRUE,
      '#module' => t('Apache Solr'),
    );
  }

  return $batch;

}
```

Then you can just use variable_get to retrieve the value on that domain.

Comment: Can you just use `variable_get()`, or do you need to use `domain_conf_variable_get()` as mentioned in Enxebre's answer?

Comment: You can use `variable_get` for the current domain value. If you want the value for a different domain, use `domain_conf_variable_get`